# How can I apply a jQuery Function to a newly created DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a menu and submenu items all async.

It seems like everytime I create a button Element using AJAX, the Javascript created on `$(document).ready` isn't working on it, which makes sense because it was created after the document ready.  But what do I use to catch newly created elements?

This is the function in question, for all the buttons with `.additem` on it when the page is loaded, it works perfectly, but when the new button is created with `.additem` it doesn't work at all.

So I believe the javascript isn't being called on the new element.  I've done several tests and I'm confident that's the case, but of course I could be wrong.

```
$('document').ready(function(){


$('.additem').click( function(e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('test')
    const category_id = $(this).attr('id');
    const url = `/add_item/${category_id}/`;
    const name = $(`.newitemname${category_id}`).val();
    const price = $(`.newitemprice${category_id}`).val();
    const description = $(`.newitemdescription${category_id}`).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        'name':name,
        'price':price,
        'description':description,
      },
      success:function(response) {
        console.log('success', response);
        $(`.itemlist${response['category_id']}`).append($(`
          <li class="row"> 
            <div class="fw-normal mb-0 col-8"> ${response['item_name']} </div> 
            <div class="col-3 text-muted pl-5" align="right">$ ${response['item_price']}</div>
            <p class="fw-lighter lh-sm" style="font-size: 12px;"> ${response['item_description']} </p> 
          </li>
        `));
      },
      error:function(response){
        console.log('error', response)
      },
    });

})
```

I've tried `$().click` but it doesn't apply to the newly created buttons for some reason.

It works on the elements that are already on the page just fine though.

I've also tried `$().change()` but it creates multiple copies of the same script.  So that when I click the button it does it +1 times everytime I click the button.  Ending up creating like 5 of the same item everytime I click `.additem`.

Comment: Do `$('.additem').on('click', function(e) {`

Comment: Yoo that worked man thank you!  Why in the world did .click not work and .on("click", works?  what the heck!!

Comment: Nice. To understand the difference, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, if you want event handlers to fire on elements `'.additem'` that are added *after* the event handler is bound you need to use 'delegated' event handlers, see https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

```
$(document).on('click', '.additem', function(e) { } );
```

Here you need to remember to attach that handler to a **parent** element of all target elements (I used `document` in this example).